# socket.io-stream with Reactjs .jsx

Tags: reactjs, socket.io-stream

I have a problem when I require 'socket. io-stream' in *.jsx
The errors show here:
[image]

And my code:
[image]

Could you tell me know why it takes and how to fix it? Thank you very much. I know my English is not good so I hope you forgive mistake grammar

I install 'npm install socket.io-stream' from 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream?activeTab=readme'

If I can't use socket.io-stream. Could you suggest me technicality to stream image from client to server through socket.io

Comment: You use this code in react js code , so it will be compiled and run on browser. Did you follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream?activeTab=readme in the document?

Comment: I copy node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js to src/public/ . But when I run code "import "../public/socket.io-stream.js" in App.js the problem show:                         
Line 1:128:     'define' is not defined